# how to split string in javascript using RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex

There is a string:

```
var str = "a1c a12c a23c ac 1234 abc";
```

and a RegExp:

```
var re = /a(\d*)c/g;
```

I want to **split** `str` by **number** that between `a` and `c`, the result I want is:

```
['a','c a','c a','c a','c 1234 abc']
```

how to do it?

Comment: shouldn't the result be ['a','c a','c a','c ac 1234 abc'] ?

Comment: @marvel308 sorry! Why the result should be  `['a','c a','c a','c ac 1234 abc']`? I want result is `['a','c a','c a','c a','c 1234 abc']`. I want to split `ac` too.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to replace numbers with a *special character* (`'-'` in this case), and split with that character.

```
str.replace(/a(\d*)c/g, 'a-c').split('-');
```

```js
var str = "a1c a12c a23c ac 1234 abc";
var re = /a(\d*)c/g;

console.log(str.replace(re, 'a-c').split('-'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a positive look ahead.

```js
var str = "a1c a12c a23c ac 1234 abc";

console.log(str.split(/\d*(?=\d*c.*a)/));
```

Comment: Thanks! But if `str = "b1c a12c a23c ac 1234 abc"`, the result is wrong.

Comment: @Guo, please add the wanted result as well.

Comment: I wanted result is `['b1c a','c a','c a','c 1234 abc']`, in fact, reslut is `['b','c a','c a','c a','c 1234 abc']`

Comment: @Guo question how `b1c a` got parse to `"b", "c a"`?