# Range vs character in Negative lookbehind in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I was answering following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42386173/how-to-split-string-in-javascript-using-regexp/42386221#) when I found this unusual problem.

Pattern: `a<n digits>b` and regex should capture `<n digits>`

In my first approach, I tried making pattern specific to characters and tried `/(?!a)\d*(?=c)/g;`

```js
var str = "a1c a12c a23c ac 1234 abc";
var str2 = "b1c a12c a23c ac 1234 ab1c"
var re = /(?!a)\d*(?=c)/g;

console.log(str.split(re))
```

In my second attempt, I tried to make pattern little more generic and tried `/(?![a-z])\d*(?=[a-z])/g`

```js
var str = "a1c a12c a23c ac 1234 abc";
var str2 = "b1c a12c a23c ac 1234 ab1c"
var re = /(?![a-z])\d*(?=[a-z])/g;

console.log(str.split(re))
```

In my understanding, this would check every character for previous value as character and next value also as character. Also since I have used `\d*` it should split `ac` as `["a", "c"]` (*which is not happening in this regex but working in previous one*).

So my question is apart from choice of characters, what is the difference in these regex:

- `/(?!a)\d*(?=c)/g`
- `/(?![a-z])\d*(?=[a-z])/g`

**Note:** I'm not asking for correct regex. If you can solve it, please post in the mentioned post. This question is specific to difference in mentioned regex

Comment: If we remove the digits at all, `(?![a-z])(?=[a-z])` can never be true, right?

Comment: Could you clarify which regex you refer to in the sentence *which is not happening in this regex but working in previous one*, please?

Comment: @SebastianProske Apologies but I'm very average in regex. My understanding was `(?![a-z])` would look for a character behind. Which is wrong assumption.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub in first example, `ac` is getting split in `["a", "c"]` but thats not happening in second one. As mentioned in comment by SebastianProske, there is gap in my understanding and will have to read more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lets first take a look at what your regex does:

- `(?!a)` check that the next character is not an `a`
- `\d*` match any amount of digits
- `(?=c)` check that the next character is a `c`

In this one, the `(?!a)` is rather pointless, as the next character is a digit or `c` according to the rest of the pattern. (e.g. it will also split `b1c` into `b` and `c`)  You might have been looking for a lookbehind (not supported in JS) `(?<=a)` to check that the previous character was an `a`.

According to your comment you seem to be confusing negative lookahead `(?!pattern)` and (positive) lookbehind `(?<=pattern)`

The second regex is quite similar, except that you check for generic (lowercase) letters instead of certain ones. If there is no digit in between those letters (`ac`), one can simplify your regex to `(?![a-z])(?=[a-z])`

- `(?![a-z])` check that the next character is no letter
- `(?=[a-z])` check that the next character is a letter

This can never be true.

Comment: I got confused with positive lookbehind and negative lookahead. Thanks :-)